# Problem using F12 to get specific info on the screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, safari

I hope I will be able to properly give my question as I am not a native English speaker and I might be running into difficulty. But I am posting an image to make my problem straight forward.

I’m new to Mac. Had my Mac Book Pro for roughly 1 month. I ran into a specific problem that I just could not solve.

I’ll start out with how I solved the problem in Windows. And my question is how I should have done it in OSX Mavericks.

I had specific instructions from someone to visit a website and prepare a print screen.
So I went up on the website with Safari and wanted to start print screening as per my instructions. In order to make my print screen more legitimate - according to my instructions - I had to press F12 and on the lower part of the monitor I should have gotten a window where I could choose from different options. I had specific instructions what to look for in the window that popped up with the F12 key.

I looked through many websites but couldn’t find a solution to my problem as my F12 key didn’t function as it should have in Mac. I tried altering the function keys in the keyboard settings but that didn’t work either. So in the end I took out my old Windows laptop and solved the problem with that. Mind you the correct window that I needed for my specific purpose did not pop up in Firefox or Internet Explorer. I needed to download Google Chrome. (The window that popped up in Firefox and Explorer with the use of F12 did not give me the options I needed).

I hope someone has the patience to read through the above. Also please take a look at the attachment I provide. I would need to reach the same result on my Mac Book Pro as I did in Windows. I do not know what the pop up window is called. But I’m sure someone who is more computer literate than I am will definitely know.

In the attachment provided I am looking to get the window which is on the lower one third of the picture that has “Elements, Network, Sources, Timeline, Profiles” etc.

Thank you for your help.
Gabi
[image: for stack exchange]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, right-click anywhere on the page and select `Inspect element`. This will bring up that window on both Mac or Windows.

**Alternatively,**

For Windows:
Click on the menu (the little button on the top-right, with 3 orange horizontal lines in your screenshot). Click on `Tools` > `Developer tools`.
**or**
Click `Ctrl+Shift+I`

For Mac:
Click on `View` > `Developer` > `Developer tools`
**or**
Click `command+option/alt+I`

If you want the F keys to work *more like* Windows, follow these steps:

**NOTE:** After following these steps, I was still unable to bring up the Developer Tools using F12 on my Macbook.

1. Go to System Preferences. Click Keyboard. On the `Keyboard` tab, check `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`. You will now have to press the fn key to make the F keys do what they show in their pictures. For example, you will have to press `fn+F11` and `fn+F12` to turn up and down your speaker volume (or at least thats where the volume controls are on my Macbook).

[image: Step 1]

2. In the same window, click on the `Shortcuts` tab. Uncheck any shortcuts that use F keys.

[image: Step 2]

Your function keys should now behave more like Windows function keys, **though not always exactly the same**.

Comment: The shortcut for Developer tools in Chrome on Windows is `Ctrl+Shift+I`. I'm not even sure why `F12` brings up that window at all, but it does.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is remaping F keys complicated. Normally I do not use them too much. In Windows the most frequent keys were F4 and F11. I do miss the print screen button though. I think print screen is a bit more tedious in OSX than in Windows. But then again I've been a Windows user for over 20 years. I'll have to adjust to the Mac ways :))

Comment: I've updated my answer with some directions. That's the best I can do!

Comment: Also, press `command+shift+3` to take screenshots on Mac. Check this website if you wanna be fancy and take screenshots of only snippets of the screen or whatnot: http://www.printscreenmac.com/

Comment: I was looking for this F12 functionality as well that somehow disappeared when I installed `Karabiner-Elements`. The location of the `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` checkbox on my MacBook's `Keyboard` tab of my keyboard settings is different than in your screenshot but it does exactly what you described. Also, I did not have to do anything on the `Shortcuts` tab to restore Chrome's F12 functionality.